# Angularjs http interceptor causing no routing to happen

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add an $http interceptor so I can add Authorization header but when I add it all routing stops working but no errors are thrown.

```
app.service('APIInterceptor', ['userService', function (userService) {
    this.request = function (config) {
        var currentUser = userService.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + currentUser.access_token;
        }

        return config;
    }
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/login", {
            templateUrl: 'Views/login.html?' + $.now(),
            controller: 'loginController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: 'Views/home.html?' + $.now(),
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });

    // when I comment out the below the routing works
    // with this line in all routing stops working
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('APIInterceptor');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with some console.log() inside the interceptor it looks like it does get in there but if there are any errors inside it doesn't report anything. I have getCurrentUser() instead of GetCurrentUser(). Kind of a bummer no errors are able to come back but got this working now.